Convert the same local time to UTC on different dates, respecting the local DST status
I have several local time points:
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo as zi

wmr = datetime.time(hour=12, tzinfo=zi("GMT"))
ecb = datetime.time(hour=14, minute=15, tzinfo=zi("CET"))
jpx = datetime.time(hour=14, tzinfo=zi("Japan"))

which I want to convert to UTC times given a date.
E.g.,
local2utc(datetime.datetime(2024,1,1), wmr) ---> "2024-01-01 12:00:00" 
local2utc(datetime.datetime(2024,6,1), wmr) ---> "2024-06-01 11:00:00" (DST active)
local2utc(datetime.datetime(2024,1,1), ecb) ---> "2024-01-01 13:15:00" 
local2utc(datetime.datetime(2024,6,1), ecb) ---> "2024-06-01 12:15:00" (DST active)
local2utc(datetime.datetime(2024,1,1), jpx) ---> "2024-01-01 05:00:00" 
local2utc(datetime.datetime(2024,6,1), jpx) ---> "2024-06-01 05:00:00" (no DST in Japan)

The following implementation
def local2utc(date, time):
    local_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(date,time)
    tm = local_dt.utctimetuple()
    return datetime.datetime(*tm[:7])

seems for work for Japan and CET, but not for GMT/WET (because London is on BST/WEST in the summer).
So, what do I do?

besides, "CET" (Central European Time) is not a time zone in a strict sense, but merely a UTC offset (+1) that multiple time zones (IANA identifiers) can experience during some period of the year. A suitable IANA identifier would be "Europe/Berlin" for instance.

Python uses the IANA time zone database.  The list of time zone names can be found here.  According to this table, "GMT" is a time zone that has a 0 UTC offset and does not observe daylight saving.
Perhaps "Europe/London" would give you the results you are looking for.

Right, this did it! Thank you!

to be precise, Python's zoneinfo module uses the IANA db. Vanilla Python comes with a timezone type, but no rules.

I might be confused by the question but have you tried the following?
>>> import datetime
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo as zi
wmr = datetime.time(hour=12, tzinfo=zi("GMT"))
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime(2024,1,1), wmr).astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime(2024,6,1), wmr).astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 1, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)


thank you, this is much better than my code!
